# Can I resume a git tf clone?

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I have a very large code in TFS and I have to clone it along with all previous history, so it takes more than 10 hours to clone.

Due to the connectivity issue, the cloning gets interrupted and I am unable to complete the clone.

Is there a way to pause and resume the cloning process. I checked everywhere, but I see only articles about resuming git tfs clone, but I need to resume **git tf clone**.

I am using the below command to clone.

> git tf clone "Server_URL" "Server_folder_path" "Local_folder_path" --deep

Here is the screenshot
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmZb2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that the `Git tf clone` doesn't support to resume.

Since Git-TF has reached its [end-of-life](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gittf), there are few documents related to it.

So I run the `Git-tf clone --help` to check the supported arguments, and the arguments don't support the recovery feature.

[image: Supported arguments]

If you want to resume the clone process,  you could try with [Git-TFS tool](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) instead of git-tf.

In Git-tfs, you could add `--resumable` argument and resume the git tfs clone.

Here is a doc about the [Git tfs clone](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/clone.md).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using quick-clone with a two year old changeset. However, the resumeable option seems not to be present in quick-clone. Unfortunately, I am receiving an error after about an hour, that the connection is broken or 'TF400030: The local data store is currently in use by another operation. Please wait and then try your operation again. If this error persists, restart the application.'

Is it possible to call quick-clone with an even older changeset and afterwards continue with a newer one? I could add changesets for each year...

Later, I want to get the history for the last two years. But I need to gtet he quick-clone work first.

Comment: I am currently using a far older changeset number. If it works, how can I fetch or pull changesets from that number to e.g. a changeset one year in advance without history? I did not find a quick-fetch command? For the final two years I would just call the fetch command with the history.